# Draw an image partially from bottom to top

Tags: vb.net, image-processing

I have the code below to draw a partial image according to the value given in `numericalUpDown` control:

```
'Creates a new Bitmap from an existing image
Dim cards As New Bitmap(My.Resources.bar)
' Draws the rectangle
Dim srcRect As New Rectangle(0, 0, 22, NumericUpDown1.Value)
' Clones the partial image from the original image
Dim card As Bitmap = DirectCast(cards.Clone(srcRect, cards.PixelFormat), Bitmap)
'Locates the new image into the picturebox
PictureBox1.Image = card
```

It starts painting from top to down, but I want to start showing the image partials from bottom to top.

Any ideas?

Comment: This feature is not in-built. You will have to build your own control somehow.

Comment: Are you attempting to put several cards on the same PictureBox?

Comment: No, I am just trying to paint the image by percentage, for example, if numericalUpDown value is 10 I want to show %10 of the image from bottom to top.